# Not able to find Xcode generated Swift header when running under -cal target

Tags: ios, calabash

I'm encountering a bit of a weird issue. Calabash works for me up until a specific. I've tried narrowing down the issue and I believe it is being caused by importing the Xcode generated Swift header file, as it's always the same error:

```
'<projectName>-Swift.h' file not found
```

I've tried changing the name of the import from `<projectName>-Swift.h` to `<projectName>-cal-Swift.h` with no luck. I've tried removing the `-force-load` compile flag, also with no luck.

If anyone has encountered a similar issue and solved it, I'd love some help!

Edit: I should mention, when not running on the `-cal` target, everything works as expected, so it's something inside the `-cal` target causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue. It required two steps under the *project* build settings

- Change the `Defines Module` setting to Yes
- Change your `Project Module Name` to what the expected name in the `projectName-Swift.h` file is. e.g. - if you expect the header to be called `MyAwesomeApp-Swift.h`, change the `Project Module Name` to `MyAwesomeApp`.